# Vuejs: get parameters from url in js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a url : `http://local-pr.local?id=12`

In **page.vue** :

- I use : `console.log(this.$route.query.id)` and get it successfully.

And now I want to get that params in the file : **page.js**

```
import addon from './addon'
import user from './user'

// I want to check if there is a new params id that has it export default
if (this.$route.query.id) {
   export default [...addon, ...user]
}
```

- `console.log(this.$route.query.id)`

ERROR: **Reason: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$route')**

Is there any way to get params in js file? Please give me some experience. Thank you.

Comment: what's the content of `page.js` file and how do you use it?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have edited the question. My `page.js` is that simple.

Comment: and how do you use that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could export a function that takes the `$route` as parameter :

```js
import addon from './addon'
import user from './user'

export default function  checkParams(route) {
   if(this.$route.query.id){
    return [...addon, ...user]
  }
}
```

and in any component you could do :

```js
import checkParams from './page.js'

.....

let data=checkParams(this.$route)
```